# dataset and Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Seem to be having an issue with using `element.dataset` in Internet Explorer.

Getting this error

> Unable to get property 'menu' of undefined or null reference

This appears on the following line of code:

```
if (!node instanceof HTMLElement || !node.dataset.menu) {
```

**---------------------------------------**

If I use Google Chrome and enter the following command:

> document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]')

I get the following:

[image]

However if I run the same command in Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

It seems to have found the 2 `[data-menu]` attributes, however doesn't list them so the NodeList is empty, hence my error.

Anyone know a solution to this issue?

**Edit**

After further investigation, it does appear that IE is generating a list NodeList of the matching elements with the `data-menu` attribute, however it doesn't appear they can be access using `dataset` like any other browser would.

Solutions?

Comment: Have you tried using `getAttribute()`? IE 11 should support `dataset`, but try using an 11- fallback. Do you have IE Compatibility mode enabled?

Comment: Problem is i'm using the querySelector to get a list of my required elements, I would have to have a reference to the element some other way to use getAttribute on it.

Comment: [`[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]'), function(value, index, array) {  /*...*/ })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control) could help if I understand you properly.

Comment: @MartynBall. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Mark due to this being asked 2 years ago I can't remember. But i'd imagine adding a polyfill for dataset would solve the issue.

Comment: So, I just search for a polyfill for a dataset? Or have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple change `if (!node instanceof HTMLElement || !node.dataset.menu)` into `if (!node instanceof HTMLElement || !node.dataset || !node.dataset.menu)`

Comment: That won't solve the problem, it needs to check that the dataset has menu in it. The issue is with Internet Explorer and dataset, as you can see I put that command below to see what it contained and it said undefined :S

Answer (score -1):

Came across the same problem just now. You can solve it by using `jQuery` instead of Vanilla JS if that is an option

Answer (score -1):

when is question too old?

Anyway, is the browser running in IE Compatibility mode? That could affect how the query selector works on data-*